Recover from disk failure using mirrored volumes
I have a system set up with Windows 11 and two drives. The disks have been converted to dynamic disks and the boot volume has been mirrored. As far as I can tell only the "primary" disk can be booted. The mirror cannot.

Is there some way to make it so that the mirror is independently bootable?
If not then, if the disk with the bootable volume dies, how would I go about doing a recovery such that I return to my original state? (Buy a new, matching disk, replace the dead one, and then...?)

Further research seems to say that recovery is a matter of getting replacement drive, install windows on it, boot into that new installation's recovery environment, mount the new boot partition and the old boot mirror, use robocopy /mir to overwrite the new boot partition with the old mirror's contents, verify the copy, boot into the overwritten installation, convert the installation to dynamic, delete the mirror, convert the new dynamic to mirrored with the old mirror drive as the new mirror.
